# Using strtok to find pair of token

Tags: c, split, char, c-strings, strtok

I am solving this homework problem: Find a pair of adjacent words in the text, such that both words begin in the same letter.

I understand that I need to use `strtok` function to solve this problem.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void) {
    char testString[] = "In the end, we will remember not the words of our enemies, but the silence of our friends";
    char *context = testString;
    const char *token = strtok_s(testString, ", ", &context);

    while (token) {
            token = strtok_s(NULL, ", ", &context);
            printf(" %s\n", token);
        }
    _getch();
}
```

In that case I have two question:

1. I don't understand why `printf` starting print from the second word?
2. What I need to do next to find word pair, how I can get access to letters of token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find *two consecutive tokens* which have *the same initial character*, right?

So you need to store the previous token when retrieving a next one, so that you can compare their initial characters and possibly print them.

**Edited:** your use of `strtok_s` seems incorrect. I fixed my mistake in the code below *and* replaced a wrong use of `strtok_s` with a correct use of `strtok`.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char testString[] = "In the end, we will remember not the words of our enemies, but the silence of our friends";
    const char *token_prev = strtok(testString, ", ");
    const char *token_next = strtok(NULL, ", ");

    while (token_next) {
        if (token_next[0] == token_prev[0]) {
            printf(" %s %s\n", token_prev, token_next);
            // break; // to print the first pair only
        }
        token_prev = token_next;
        token_next = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    }
}
```

See it working at GodBolt: https://godbolt.org/z/YzjcPKrq6

This will iterate through the whole input string and print all pairs found. If you add a `break;` after `printf()` under `if()` then it will print the first pair only.

Comment: nicely done. But someone has edit my question and the task actualy is:
the last letter of the second word is equal to the first letter of the first word.

so may I use the following expression:
if (token_next[strlen(token_next) - 1] == token_prev[0])
but nothing comes right

Comment: @КириллБоровой Your use of `strtok_s` seems incorrect. I fixed my mistake in the code above _and_ replaced a wrong use of `strtok_s` with a correct use of `strtok`. See it working at GodBolt.

Comment: @КириллБоровой What concerns the task definition, you wrote _'Find in the text a pair of words to a neighbor, the second of which begins with the same letter that the first of this pair begins with.'_ – clearly both words have to _begin_ with the same letter (as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67787703/1)).

Comment: @КириллБоровой As for the change you propose in your comment (the first letter of the first token and the last one of the second one must be equal) : yes, it works as desired when applied to the fixed code. Please see here: https://godbolt.org/z/zdbbcvoeq

Comment: YEAH!!!! That`s good, working perfectly. You are the wizard!

Answer (score 1):

1. `printf` starts printing from the second word because you never print the first token, i.e. the one you've obtained from the initial call to `strtok_s` before entering the loop.
2. Token is a regular C string. Its initial letter is `token[0]`, a `char`. You can store it in a separate `char` variable, and carry it over into the next iteration of the loop.
3. Since the words could be in mixed case, you should probably use `toupper` or `tolower` when storing and comparing the initial characters.

Answer (score 1):

You extracted the first word in this statement

```
const char *token = strtok_s(testString, ", ", &context);
```

but you did not print it. You are starting to print words in the while loop after the preceding call of strtok_s within the loop.

You need two pointers that will point to adjacent extracted strings and using these pointers you can compare first letters of the strings.

Here is a demonstrative program (for simplicity I am using strtok instead of strtok_s)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char testString[] = "In the end, we will remember not the words "
                        "of our enemies, but the silence of our friends";
                        
    char *first_word  = NULL;
    char *second_word = NULL;
    
    const char *delim = ", ";
    
    if ( ( first_word = strtok( testString, delim ) ) != NULL )
    {
        while ( ( second_word = strtok( NULL, delim ) ) != NULL && 
                *first_word != *second_word )
        {
            first_word = second_word;           
        }
    }
    
    if ( second_word != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%s <-> %s\n", first_word, second_word );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
we <-> will
```

If you want to output all such pairs of words then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char testString[] = "In the end, we will remember not the words "
                        "of our enemies, but the silence of our friends";
                        
    char *first_word  = NULL;
    char *second_word = NULL;
    
    const char *delim = ", ";
    
    if ( ( first_word = strtok( testString, delim ) ) != NULL )
    {
        while ( ( second_word = strtok( NULL, delim ) ) != NULL )
        {
            if ( *first_word == *second_word )
            {
                printf( "%s <-> %s\n", first_word, second_word );
            }
            first_word = second_word;           
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
we <-> will
of <-> our
of <-> our
```

However instead of using `strtok` or `strtok_s` it is much better to use an approach based on the functions `strspn` and `strcspn`. In this case you can process constant strings.